# Estilo de editText en Android con sombra similar al buscador de Google

Tags: android, edittext

¿Cómo puedo lograr un estilo para un `editText` en Android como el de la siguiente imagen?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La parte de la lupa es un botón, también el editText tiene una sombra muy similar a la que está usando el editText del buscador Google (*el `editText` de la imagen tiene una pequeña sombra que en la imagen no se logra observar muy bien*).

Ese diseño lo hice para web y estoy comenzando en Android (usando Android Studio).

Y si es posible, me gustaría poder hacer la misma animación que la barra de google animación: cuando se coloca el mouse encima o se le da tap (en caso del móvil) entonces que la sombra se muestre más grande.

Comment: Puedes usar un cardview, añadirle un edittext a la izquierda y un botón con imagen a la derecha. No tiene mucha dificultad.

Comment: quieres que el edittext este siempre visible? o que aparezca?

Comment: @FabioVenturiPastor si puedo hacer eso, pero el estilo del editText, podré modificarlo para que se muestre como el de la imagen? 
gracias por contestar

Comment: @Maguz que esté siempre visible :)

Comment: ¿la imagen de buscar es un boton o solo un imageView?, edita tu pregunta agrega más detalles de lo que buscas

Comment: @ReneLimon he editado la pregunta, la imagen es de un input realizado para web

Comment: Tengo un diseño similar,si lo deseas te lo puedo dejar, esta en mysql, php y android studio ...

Answer (score 1):

después de un rato logré estos estilos:
en el layout del activity usar este código para el editText y para un ImageButton:

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textAutoCorrect"
        android:hint="@string/hintext_buscar"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editTextBuscar"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext_border"
        android:elevation="2.5dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btnBuscar" />

<ImageButton
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/searchicon"
        android:id="@+id/btnBuscar"
        android:paddingTop="18.5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="18.5dp"
        android:contentDescription="buscarbtn"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

Y crear un xml en drawable con el siguiente código:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Background Color -->
    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
    <!-- Border Color -->
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#ffffff" />
    <!-- Round Corners -->
    <corners android:radius="1dp" />
    <padding android:top="12dp" android:bottom="12dp"></padding>

</shape>
```